# Is there an easy way to shorten URL's with parameters in Objective C using goo.gl?

Tags: objective-c, url-shortener, google-url-shortener

This does not seem to be working:

```
NSString *key = @"mykey";

NSString *shortenedStrURL = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=%@&longUrl=%@", key,strURL]] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

return [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
```

Comment: You could use the error parameter to see what error is returned?

Comment: `return [NSURL URLWithString:shortenedStrURL];` Try this.